# Intermittent Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with multiple sheets. In sheet3 I have a button (named button1) which is used to run the following code which is working well when using button1:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Call PivotColor(Sheet3, "1Up", "1Down", 30, 6)

End Sub
```

And hereby his the code behind the function "PivotColor":

```
Sub PivotColor(Sheetname As Worksheet, UpArrow As String, DownArrrow As String, Columnreference As Integer, Rowreference As Integer)

If (Sheetname.Cells(Rowreference, Columnreference) >= 0) Then

    ' Select RED Arrow
    Sheetname.Shapes.Range(Array(DownArrrow)).Select

    ' Hide the Red Arrow
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Transparency = 1
        .Solid
    End With


' Otherwise it means the value of the cells is negative...
Else

    ' Select RED Arrow
    Sheetname.Shapes.Range(Array(DownArrrow)).Select

    ' Display the Red Arrow
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With

End If
End Sub
```

Now if I create a new button (named button2) in the second sheet (named sheet2) and associate the same code to it, I have the error "Object doesn't support this property or method".

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Call PivotColor(Sheet3, "1Up", "1Down", 30, 6)

End Sub
```

If I click on "debug" it is highlighted this line:

```
With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
```

So basically, here the idea is to execute a process that should happened on sheet3 but launch it from sheet2.

I don't understand what's it not working... Any ideas ?

Comment: When you have clicked debug, can you see whether the down arrow has been selected?  has it been selected?

Comment: I think it was selected as the "debug" button is highlighting the very next code line after [ Sheetname.Shapes.Range(Array(DownArrrow)).Select ].

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `.Select` and `Selection` is likely generating confusion. When you click the button on Sheet3, you are on Sheet3 (ActiveSheet). Not so when clicking the button on Sheet2. Try to code without using `.Select`.

```
Sub PivotColor(Sheetname As Worksheet, UpArrow As String, DownArrrow As String, Columnreference As Integer, Rowreference As Integer)

    With Sheetname
        ' Show/Hide the Red Arrow
        With .Shapes(DownArrrow).ShapeRange.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .Transparency = Abs(.Cells(Rowreference, Columnreference) >= 0)
            .Solid
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

A single shape does not require the whole `.Shapes.Range(Array(...))` code. I've tightened up the code by evaluating the boolean result directly into the `.Transparency` property=s value.

Comment: Sorry but even with this code I still have the same error message. The debug is highlighting this line:  [ ' Show/Hide the Red Arrow
        With .Shapes(DownArrrow).ShapeRange.Fill ]...

Comment: I expected the above to fix the issue. Ignore my code.

Answer (score 0):

To me you code looks ok.

I would try the following code instead of your lines, although i wouldn;t expect this to make any difference.

' Select RED Arrow
    ' Hide the Red Arrow

```
With Sheetname.Shapes.Range(Array(DownArrrow)).ShapeRange.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Transparency = 1
    .Solid
End With
```

Also, 
In Sheet2 is there a variable declared at module level called "Sheet3" if so it is grabbing this instead of using the "sheet3" worksheet object. - Just a thought.

Comment: I still have the same error message. The debug is highlighting this line: [ With Sheetname.Shapes.Range(Array(DownArrrow)).ShapeRange.Fill ]

Comment: How can I make sure it is using "Sheet3" worksheet object (in Sheet2 code) ?